# Is Vaadin's CssImport annotation broken?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, vaadin14

we've used Vaadin 14.5 and the `@CssImport` for custom CSS worked fine.
Now we wanted to update but since 14.6 the `@CssImport` doesn't load the custom CSS anymore.

We have the following Maven structure:

```
- app-1, -2... : the apps that have common code and style

- shared : all the code and style we share between our apps
 |
 +- src/main/java/our/package/AbstractUI.java
 |
  - src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/
   |
   +- css
      |  
      +-styles.css
      |
       - vaadin-vertical-layout.css
```

In the shared artifact we have several custom CSS files for Vaadin components, where we address the CSS that has to be adjusted in the shadow DOMs:

```css
vaadin-vertical-layout.css
/* Page */
:host(.Page) {
    left: 64px;
    padding-top: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    width: calc(100% - 64px);
}
```

And then we load all these custom CSS in the class `AbstractUI`, that is the super class for all the other UI classes:

```java
@StyleSheet("./css/styles.css")
...
@CssImport(value = "./css/vaadin-vertical-layout.css", themeFor = "vaadin-vertical-layout")
@Theme(value = Material.class, variant = Material.LIGHT)
public abstract class AbstractUI extends VerticalLayout {
```

The apps then don't have to bother with all the annotations and can simply extend `AbstractUI` and the CSS is loaded and added to the existing shadow DOM CSS.

That worked fine with Vaadin 14 up to 14.5.5, but after 14.6.0 the custom CSS is no longer loaded. The `vaadin-maven-plugin` does check for the existence of the CSS files when building the frontend (and quits with an error if they aren't there), but in the application
the CSS just isn't loaded.
To clarify: the `@StyleSheet` annotation still works, so that CSS is loaded.

Is this a bug in Vaadin or do we miss some critical information?

Comment: Could you give some code sample on this as using https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow/tree/v14 with 14.7.4 (also 14.6.0) the `CssImport` works as it should in that case. With default lumo and defined material theme. So I don't really know what extra to try with in this case.

Comment: I've created a minimum working example (with the structure in my question) to post here - and it works. I'm now officially confused as I haven't a clue what's the difference. When I've found it, I will report.

Comment: @MikaelGrankvist the problem got caused by the plugin "tinymce-for-flow", which prior to the newest version had a resource path that contained "themes".

Comment: I've created an issue on Github for this: https://github.com/vaadin/platform/issues/2596

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical information missing was a Vaadin webcomponent named "TinyMCE for Flow" that was the reason for this behavior. Don't know why it broke so much.
The solution was to update it to the newest version (3.1.1).